# Html y Css atascada en un paso

Tags: html, css, float

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio, ahora sigo avanzando y estoy atascado en una cosa:

Necesito que la lista aparezca debajo del div de password, pero se me monta encima. Además, tiene que estar esta lista dividida en dos columnas (izq y drch).

Todo esto tengo que hacerlo sin usar flex, ni grid.

Este es mi código y aun poniendo float y margin, se me monta, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal:

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO POR CUALQUIER AYUDA!

///

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="columnaizq">
        <img src="./Imágenes/logomono.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="columnadrch">
                <div class="titulo">
                <h1>Welcome to Mailchimp</h1>
                <p class="log">La primera vez que inicies sesión en tu cuenta, te pediremos información obligatoria. 
                    <a class="login" href=https://login.mailchimp.com/> Log in </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div class="email1"></div>
                    <label for="email" class="email"> 
                        <p class="email">Email</p>
        
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="ema">
                    </label>
                    <div class="Username"></div>
                    <label for="user">
                        <p class="userna">Username</p> 
                        <input name="user" type="text">

                    </label>
                    <div class="password">
                        <label for="pass" class="pass">
                            <p>Password</p>
                            <input name="pass" type="password"/>
                        </label>

                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

           <div class="lista">
            <ul class="listaizq">
                <li>Una letra minúscula</li>
                <li>Una letra mayúscula</li>
                <li>Un número</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="listadrch">
                <li>Un caracter especial</li>
                <li>Mínimo 8 caracteres</li>
            </ul>

           </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>


///

*{
    width: 100%;
    
}

.columnaizq{
    width: 18%;
}

img{
   float: left;
   width: 180px;
   padding: 10%;
   margin-right: 20px;
}

.columnadrch{
   margin-left: 200px;
   width: 78% ;   
}

.titulo{
    position: relative;
    display: inline ;

}

h1{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.log{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    width: 600px;
   
}
.login{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

form{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    display: inline;
}

.email{
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.Username{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.userna{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.password{
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.pass{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.lista{
  margin-top: 30px;
   
}

.listaizq{
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;

}   

.listadrch{
float: right;

}
```

Estos serían mi HTML y mi CSS.

Seguro que es una tontería que no veo, pero llevo atascada todo el día en eso :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar y aplicar las buenas prácticas, así como algunos errores.

1. Omitiste las comillas en el valor del `href` que está en tu
   `<a></a>`. Debería ser `<a class="login" href="https://login.mailchimp.com/"> Log in </a>`. Este error provoca que tu IDE no sea capaz de reconocer las aperturas y cierre de las etiquetas, lo que conlleva a más errores de estructura si no te das cuenta. También pues no funciona el link.
2. ¿Por qué los `<label></label>` de tu formulario que son etiquetas que suelen identificar a los inputs en la interfaz de usuario están encerrando a estos y otros elementos más? Lo único que debería ir dentro de ellas es el nombre del input. Por ejemplo: `<label for="pass">Contraseña</label>`. Observa que en tu código encierras a `<p>` y a `<input>`, es incorrecto, cada uno es independiente y si se quieren agrupar, se usa `<div>`.
3. Junto con tus `<label>` tienes a `<p>` que lo utilizas para identificar el nombre de tus inputs, lo cual no está mal, pero si ya tienes el primero, no hace falta repetirlo. Igualmente, se sugiere el uso del elemento `label` antes que de `p` en los formularios.
4. Hay contenedores vacíos como `<div class="email1"></div>`. ¿Son separaciones invisibles? Si es así, mejor usa `padding` en el elemento padre ya que no aporta mucho tenerlo.
5. Antes de construir una página web (incluso trabajos de escuela) primero debes imaginar o empezar a maquetar cómo será toda la estructura de tu página web. A pesar de que te hayan dicho que no puedes usar `flexbox` o `grid`, tú puedes simularlo y usar su estructura de referencia. Como buena práctica, analiza primero cómo crees que quedarán acomodado tus elementos principales, utiliza filas, columnas y contenedores para visualizar cómo le vas a dar forma, ya que de esto dependerá de que no te confundas más adelante. Por ejemplo, esta es la forma en la que medio te lo imaginaste, pero hay otras formas de maquetar que te ayudan a distribuir mejor los elementos, ya dependerá de cómo quieres que se vea la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entre mejor definas tus contenedores (aunque se vean muchos), mayor libertad tendrás de distribuirlos y agruparlos para que no supongan un dolor de cabeza después. En la imagen todo está contenido en una fila (color rojo) y este a su vez tiene 2 columnas, a las que tú llamaste `.columnaizq` y `.columnadrch`, la izquierda tiene una imagen inmediatamente. La derecha tiene otro contenedor que agrupa a tus 3 elementos (bienvenida, formulario, lista).

Ahora bien, los detalles en CSS eran muy variados, pero básicamente se te "encimaba" tu lista porque a tu `form` le añadiste un `position: absolute` que lo sacó del flujo de elementos y quedó "flotando", entonces como el div de tu lista vio que no había nada ahí, se corrió para rellenar ese espacio.

Para mejor tu código y empieces a aprender cómo estructurar filas, columnas y agrupar correctamente elementos, primeramente reinicia el `padding` y `margin` de tu navegador para que no interfieran en tus medidas que próximamente harás:

```
*{  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;  
}
```

Ahora tus columnas principales que son `.columnaizq` y `.columnadrch` deben tener su `float` left y right, respectivamente y quitarle ese margen izquierdo forzado que pusiste (ambos deberían estar contenidos en una fila y deben sumar un `width` de 100%, si no, se saldrá del navegador).

Los 3 elementos de la derecha (bienvenida, formulario y listas) agrúpalo para que no queden flotando en la nada, este contenedor se llamará `.info-col` y asígnale un ancho.

En el formulario agrupa correctamente los `label` e `input` como verás en el código.

En tu lista puedes aplicar la propiedad `columns` para separar en 2 columnas los textos y así solo utilices una lista.

```css
*{  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;  
}

.columnaizq{
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img{
   float: left;
   width: 180px;
   padding: 10%;
   margin-right: 20px;
}

.columnadrch{
   /*margin-left: 200px;*/
   float: right;
   width: 82% ;
   border: 1px solid black;   
}

.titulo{
    position: relative;
    display: inline ;

}

h1{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.log{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    width: 600px;
   
}
.login{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

form{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


.listaizq{
float: left;
/*margin-right: 30px;*/

}   

.listadrch{
float: right;

}

.fila{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 0.5px red;
}

.grupoform{
  padding: 5px;
}

label{
  display: block;
}

input{
  width: 100%;
}

.listacols{
  columns: 2;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.info-col{
  width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Fila principal -->
  <div class="fila">
    <!-- Columna izquierda -->
    <div class="columnaizq">
        <img src="./Imágenes/logomono.png"/>
    </div>
    <!-- Columna derecha -->
    <div class="columnadrch">
        <!-- Columna que contiene los 3 elementos -->
        <div class="info-col">
          <div class="titulo">
            <h1>Welcome to Mailchimp</h1>
              <p class="log">La primera vez que inicies sesión en tu cuenta, <br> te pediremos información obligatoria. 
                <a class="login" href="https://login.mailchimp.com"> Log in </a>
              </p>
          </div>
          
          <div>
            <form>
                <div class="grupoform">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>        
                  <input name="email" type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="grupoform">
                  <label for="user">Username</label>
                  <input name="user" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="grupoform">
                  <label for="pass">Password</label>
                  <input name="pass" type="password"/>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="lista">
              <ul class="listacols">
                  <li>Una letra minúscula</li>
                  <li>Una letra mayúscula</li>
                  <li>Un número</li>
                  <li>Un caracter especial</li>
                  <li>Mínimo 8 caracteres</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola!! Antes que nada, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta tan completa, gracias gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Lo he probado y al fin se queda debajo y en dos columnas... tengo mucho que mejorar, hago demasiadas entradas y al final me vuelvo loco. Lo has hecho mucho más limpio y claro. Lo que si que no entiendo muy bien es el .infocols, ya que no hay nada en html con ese nombre, no??? Ahora me queda ajustar un poco los espacios entre las líneas pero al fin con tu GRAN ayuda puedo avanzar...  MIL GRACIAS

Comment: @Carmen no se ve que haya ningún _.infocols_. Lo que sí hay es _.info-col_ y _.listacols_.

Comment: @Carmen Hola, sí, como menciona padaleiana, es _.info-col_ y es está señalado en el 4to comentario del HTML:  `<!-- Columna que contiene los 3 elementos -->`. Su función es agrupar tu bienvenida, formulario y lista y dar un ancho fijo para que sus hijos se muevan en función a este. Saludos.